Glassfish Tools installation on eclipse
I am unable to install Glassfish on my eclipse. I am using Java 17(tried it with java 8 also) and Eclipse 2023-6. I want to see Glassfish in the server list along with Apache, IBM, Resin etc.
I have tried the Eclipse marketplace -> Install Glassfish tools and 'Install New Software' with the url  -> http://download.oracle.com/otn_software/oepe/12.2.1.8/oxygen/repository/dependencies/. Both cases failed to install glassfish tool.
This is the error I get.
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=_Users_shikhar_Eclipse-17_Eclipse.app_Contents_Eclipse,          phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jetty.jndi,10.0.17
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jetty.plus,10.0.17
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jetty.webapp,10.0.17
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jetty.xml,10.0.17


The GlassFish Tools project has been archived in November 2021. According to the GlassFish Tools Marketplace entry (when you click on the download icon), the latest supported Eclipse version is 2021-03 (4.19).

Installing eclipse 2020 worked for me.

Here’s a newer and maintained Eclipse IDE plugin for GlassFish: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/omnifish-tools-eclipse-glassfish
More info on how to install and use it: https://omnifish.ee/developers/glassfish-server/ide-plugins-for-glassfish/eclipse-ide/
The GlassFish Tools plugin is an old plugin from Oracle which is not maintained anymore by Oracle or anybody else.
